# MySQL multiple replication users

Tags: mysql, replication

I have an environment of one Master server (Master A) and three slaves (Slave B, C and D) configured with an ID called "replicator". Unfortunately credentials for "replicator" user is missing (the guy who previously configured already left the company) and my management afraid to change the password as well. At the same time I need to create new slave and want to configure replication from Slave C to Slave E (new slave).

01). How can I get this work done without impacting to current replication?

02). Is it possible to create another user in slave C and get the replication done? If this not possible?

03) Is it possible to create another user in Master and set up replication to slave E (new server)?

Your expert ideas are highly appreciated because I need to get this done without impacting to current replication.

Thanks, 
Manjula

Comment: Any thoughts please ....

Answer (score 0):

you can find replicator credentials in master.info file in the path /var/lib/mysql on slave server 
line fifth contains the username
and line sixth contains the password in clear-text